# UIImagePickerController CameraDevice picks wrong device every other time (using ARC)

Tags: iphone, ios, automatic-ref-counting

My app takes a video (using a custom overlay, in case that's relevant) where I have the cameraDevice set to front facing camera. 3 videos need to be taken, though the cameraDevice alternates between front and rear each time the **UIImpagePickerController** is called to take the video. On each occasion the

```
  picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
```

is used within the code, though as mentioned the app ignores this command every other time.

I see this problem has been asked before, though I am using ARC so the previously suggested solutions of releasing the **UIImagePickerController** is not an option for me.

Thanks in advance, Jim.

Comment: Can you provide some code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot `release` the picker in ARC but you can still create a brand new one like this:

```
picker = nil;
picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
// configure picker
```

Notice that in Apple's [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html) "Using UIImagePickerController to Select Pictures and Take Photos" they call a method each time which does exactly this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mundi. I placed the picker = nil; at the end of the class before it segued to the next view controller and this done the trick. Life saver! Answer accepted and +1 deserved!